# Is there a better way to handle calendar event files (.ics) in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: java, outlook, calendar, jakarta-mail

```
DateFormat iCalendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
        Date dTstamp = new Date();
        String start=iCalendarDateFormat.format(startDate);
        String end=iCalendarDateFormat.format(endDate);
        StringBuffer buffer = sb.append(
                                          "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
                                          "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n"
                                          + "VERSION:2.0\n" 

                /*"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" + "X-LOTUS-CHARSET:UTF-8\n"
                        + "PRODID:-//Lotus Development Corporation//NONSGML Notes 8.5//EN_C\n" + "VERSION:2.0\n"*/
                        + "METHOD:REQUEST\n" + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" + "DTSTAMP:"+dTstamp+"\n"
                        +"DTSTART:"+start+"\n" + "DTEND:"+end+"\n" + "SUMMARY:"+msg+"\n"
                        + "UID:324\n"
                        + "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"+emailAddress+"\n"
                        + "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:"+"abc@xyz.com"+"\n" +
                        /*
                         * "DTSTART:20051208T053000Z\n" +
                         * "DTEND:20051208T060000Z\n" +
                         */
                        "LOCATION:"+location+"\n" + "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" + "SEQUENCE:0\n"
                        + "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000002FF466CE3AC5010000000000000000100\n"
                        + " 000004377FE5C37984842BF9440448399EB02\n" +
                        /* "DTSTAMP:20051206T120102Z\n" + */
                        "CATEGORIES:Meeting\n" + "DESCRIPTION:"+msg+".\n\n"
                        + "SUMMARY:"+subject+"\n" + "PRIORITY:5\n" + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" + "BEGIN:VALARM\n"
                        + "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" + "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" + "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" + "END:VALARM\n"
                        + "END:VEVENT\n" + "END:VCALENDAR");

        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        // create and fill the body of the message
        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        // Fill the message
        body.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
        body.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
```

I have created calendar service using java Mail API.is there any way that without sending the file as an attachment, the user directly views the calendar event, just the same way when someone creates the event and the user accepts/rejects it.?